# SQL query to get data from record above

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Having difficulty writing a SQL query and looking for some advice/ assistance.
In the original table in `'vocab'` column I want to somehow bring back the info from the line above.

**For example -**

In Row 2('lstseqno' = 2) the 'vocab' which is -1 is actually equal to the 'vocab' of the row above ('lstseqno' = 1), so 'vocab' = 2

In Row 6('lstseqno' = 6) the 'vocab' which is -1 is actually equal to the 'vocab' of the row above ('lstseqno' = 5), so 'vocab' = 4

How would I write a query to do this?
Much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? With [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) this is typically done using the `lag()` function

Comment: What version of SQL are you on (SQL Server, Oracle, Postgresql)? If SQL Server which version is it (2005, 2008, 2012 etc)?

Comment: Novice here so not sure what you mean by DBMS.
Does SQL server help in anyway

Comment: Hi Rich - I believe SQL 2008

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select iif(t.vocab=-1, (select t2.vocab from your_table t2 
                    where t2.lstseqno=t.lstseqno-1),
                    t.vocab) as vocab,
       t.ref, t.code -- add here all other fields 
    from your_table t
```

Of course you should replace `your_table` with your actual table name. Also you may replace `-1` with you actual value (or with `is null` for empty values).

Comment: Hi Evgeny

I don't want to change the table, merely want a query that will make sense of the table

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
select actial.vocab [actual_vocab], above.vocab [above_vocab]
from original_tbl actual
left join original_tbl above on actual.lstseqno = above.lstseqno - 1
    and actual.code = above.code
    and actual.level = above.level
```